# how to remove caption setting option from caption cascading on videojs in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, video.js, caption

Actually I have used **addRemoteTextTrack** for adding custom cascading on videojs. This is working fine. But when I am clicking on caption setting option. caption i.e being duplicated. I need a solution for this problem. That may be either I hide caption settings option from video or after making some changes after which repeat ion won't be occurred.

For adding caption I have added this code on videojs.

```
player.addRemoteTextTrack({ mode: 'showing', kind: "captions", label: "English", language: "en" }, false);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "easiest" way to hide it is to set the **textTrackSettings** option to false and then add a bit of css to the page:

```
var player = videojs(videoEl, {
  // make the text track settings dialog not initialize
  textTrackSettings: false
});
```

Then in your css file:

```
/* hide the captions settings item from the captions menu */
.vjs-texttrack-settings {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css

```
.vjs-subs-caps-button {
  display: none;
}
```

if you are using styled-components you can do this to your video component container

```
const Container = styled.div`
.vjs-subs-caps-button {
  display: none;
}
```

then wrrap you video compoennt like this :

```
<Container>
  <VideoJS
    options={videoJsOptions}
  />
</Container>
```

`